# Adding FaultRule to ServiceCallout

Tags: apigee

I have been trying to make sense of the Apigee Guide on Fault Handling (http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling) but it is not making sense to me.

The following request can result in a 404 error from the target server. How do I correctly catch this fault?

```
<ServiceCallout async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="CalloutSessionSignIn">
  <Request variable="SignInRequest"/>
  <Response>SignInResponse</Response>
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>http://localhost/{service_name}/{request.formparam.session_id}/signin</URL>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is in my blog [Handling 404 backend response](http://sriki77-apigee.blogspot.in/2014/06/handling-404-backend-response.html) 
One you do the solution described, you can generate appropriate response based on `SignInResponse.status.code=404` condition.